# Books about hex board war game programming?

Tags: war, hexagonal-tiles

I plan to write a hex board war game. Any books/sites to recommend? Probably require:

- game strategy AI programming
- board (hex) representation
- turn-based game loop
- ...

(community wiki please)

Comment: Would get much more luck here I imagine: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh, didn't realize there is a dedicated so for game dev. any chance moving this question to there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a book, but [Amit's Game Programming Information](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html) has been a very useful resource for me.  His site has a section devoted to hexes and the various maths involved in dealing with them.